# JavaScript map not working

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I think it's something super simple I'm missing and I had it working earlier but for some reason, it's not working now. I think I'm linking something wrong. (Taken from [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/)). The div id is correctly located inside the body tags.

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "map",
  "theme": "none",
  path: "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",

  imagesSettings: {
    rollOverColor: "#089282",
    rollOverScale: 3,
    selectedScale: 3,
    selectedColor: "#089282",
    color: "#13564e"
  },

  areasSettings: {
    unlistedAreasColor: "#15A892"
  },

  dataProvider: {
    map: "worldLow",
    images: [{
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Brussels",
      latitude: 50.8371,
      longitude: 4.3676
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Copenhagen",
      latitude: 55.6763,
      longitude: 12.5681
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Paris",
      latitude: 48.8567,
      longitude: 2.3510
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Reykjavik",
      latitude: 64.1353,
      longitude: -21.8952
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Moscow",
      latitude: 55.7558,
      longitude: 37.6176
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Madrid",
      latitude: 40.4167,
      longitude: -3.7033
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "London",
      latitude: 51.5002,
      longitude: -0.1262,
      url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Peking",
      latitude: 39.9056,
      longitude: 116.3958
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "New Delhi",
      latitude: 28.6353,
      longitude: 77.2250
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Tokyo",
      latitude: 35.6785,
      longitude: 139.6823,
      url: "http://www.google.co.jp"
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Ankara",
      latitude: 39.9439,
      longitude: 32.8560
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Buenos Aires",
      latitude: -34.6118,
      longitude: -58.4173
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Brasilia",
      latitude: -15.7801,
      longitude: -47.9292
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Ottawa",
      latitude: 45.4235,
      longitude: -75.6979
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Washington",
      latitude: 38.8921,
      longitude: -77.0241
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Kinshasa",
      latitude: -4.3369,
      longitude: 15.3271
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Cairo",
      latitude: 30.0571,
      longitude: 31.2272
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Pretoria",
      latitude: -25.7463,
      longitude: 28.1876
    }]
  }
});


function updateCustomMarkers(event) {
  var map = event.chart;

  for (var x in map.dataProvider.images) {
    var image = map.dataProvider.images[x];

    if ('undefined' == typeof image.externalElement)
      image.externalElement = createCustomMarker(image);

    image.externalElement.style.top = map.latitudeToY(image.latitude) +
      'px';
    image.externalElement.style.left = map.longitudeToX(image.longitude) +
      'px';
  }
}

function createCustomMarker(image) {
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.className = 'map-marker';
  holder.title = image.title;
  holder.style.position = 'absolute';

  if (undefined != image.url) {
    holder.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = image.url;
    };
    holder.className += ' map-clickable';
  }

  var dot = document.createElement('div');
  dot.className = 'dot';
  holder.appendChild(dot);

  var pulse = document.createElement('div');
  pulse.className = 'pulse';
  holder.appendChild(pulse);

  image.chart.chartDiv.appendChild(holder);
  return holder;
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.map-marker {
  /* adjusting for the marker dimensions 
  so that it is centered on coordinates */
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.map-marker.map-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pulse {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #f7f14c;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #716f42;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}
.map-marker .dot {
  border: 10px solid #fff601;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="/CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: And what would be the definition of *not working* over here?

Comment: When I put your code into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), I get a map.

Comment: The home, plus, and minus icons all appear to work properly as well.

Comment: @BSMP: Your link is not working!

Comment: @PrerakSola -  It is working, it goes right to https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: OP, the code you've provided doesn't reproduce the error. Please [edit] your post so that we can re-create the problem you're having. As an aside, you can also make this a runnable snippet on the site. It's the icon that looks like a piece of paper with angle brackets (the one before the numbered list).

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver which is a horrible program so maybe that has something to do with why I can't see it?

Answer (score 0):

As the map itself shows up, using your code, I'm assuming what you're missing is the custom markers that are supposed to be displayed on the map.

For that you are missing one essential piece. The `updateCustomMarkers` function that is supposed to create those markers is never invoked.

You can use map's ["init"](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#init) event to call it. Just add the following line after your map code:

```
map.addListener("init", updateCustomMarkers);
```

Here's full updated code:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "map",
  "theme": "none",
  path: "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",

  imagesSettings: {
    rollOverColor: "#089282",
    rollOverScale: 3,
    selectedScale: 3,
    selectedColor: "#089282",
    color: "#13564e"
  },

  areasSettings: {
    unlistedAreasColor: "#15A892"
  },

  dataProvider: {
    map: "worldLow",
    images: [{
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Brussels",
      latitude: 50.8371,
      longitude: 4.3676
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Copenhagen",
      latitude: 55.6763,
      longitude: 12.5681
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Paris",
      latitude: 48.8567,
      longitude: 2.3510
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Reykjavik",
      latitude: 64.1353,
      longitude: -21.8952
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Moscow",
      latitude: 55.7558,
      longitude: 37.6176
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Madrid",
      latitude: 40.4167,
      longitude: -3.7033
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "London",
      latitude: 51.5002,
      longitude: -0.1262,
      url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Peking",
      latitude: 39.9056,
      longitude: 116.3958
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "New Delhi",
      latitude: 28.6353,
      longitude: 77.2250
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Tokyo",
      latitude: 35.6785,
      longitude: 139.6823,
      url: "http://www.google.co.jp"
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Ankara",
      latitude: 39.9439,
      longitude: 32.8560
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Buenos Aires",
      latitude: -34.6118,
      longitude: -58.4173
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Brasilia",
      latitude: -15.7801,
      longitude: -47.9292
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Ottawa",
      latitude: 45.4235,
      longitude: -75.6979
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Washington",
      latitude: 38.8921,
      longitude: -77.0241
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Kinshasa",
      latitude: -4.3369,
      longitude: 15.3271
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Cairo",
      latitude: 30.0571,
      longitude: 31.2272
    }, {
      zoomLevel: 5,
      scale: 0.5,
      title: "Pretoria",
      latitude: -25.7463,
      longitude: 28.1876
    }]
  }
});

map.addListener("init", updateCustomMarkers);

function updateCustomMarkers(event) {

  var map = event.chart;

  for (var x in map.dataProvider.images) {

    var image = map.dataProvider.images[x];

    if ('undefined' == typeof image.externalElement)
      image.externalElement = createCustomMarker(image);

    image.externalElement.style.top = map.latitudeToY(image.latitude) +
      'px';
    image.externalElement.style.left = map.longitudeToX(image.longitude) +
      'px';
  }
}

function createCustomMarker(image) {
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.className = 'map-marker';
  holder.title = image.title;
  holder.style.position = 'absolute';

  if (undefined != image.url) {
    holder.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = image.url;
    };
    holder.className += ' map-clickable';
  }

  var dot = document.createElement('div');
  dot.className = 'dot';
  holder.appendChild(dot);

  var pulse = document.createElement('div');
  pulse.className = 'pulse';
  holder.appendChild(pulse);

  image.chart.chartDiv.appendChild(holder);

  return holder;
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
width   : 100%;
height  : 500px;
}

.map-marker {
/* adjusting for the marker dimensions 
so that it is centered on coordinates */
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -8px;}

 .map-marker.map-clickable {
cursor: pointer;}
 .pulse {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #f7f14c;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #716f42;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}
.map-marker .dot {
    border: 10px solid #fff601;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: -25px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```